# I need to use sed in Linux to find a portion of a line in XML and update a value in it?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, xml

I have a requirement to update a variable value in XML with a fixed value once there is a partial match in XML using `sed` on Linux.

Example:

Input value:

```xml
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=1234" DBaction="A" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.02,6.03,6.04">
```

The requirement is to update the version value with only 6.02 whenever "6.02" is there in version value. So, output would be like:

```xml
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=1234" DBaction="A" version="6.02">
```

Note: `tableName="Data"` is fixed value but `PGPU_ID`, `DBaction` and `version` can be different. So whenever `tablename ="Data"` and `version` is `6.02`, then the `sed` command should replace the version with only 6.02 keeping other values exactly the same.

Comment: Welcome to the site. For structured data like XML and JSON, it is better to use dedicated parsing tools like `xmlstarlet` or `JQ` instead of line-oriented tools like `sed` or `awk` because the same data can end up formatted in different ways. Do you really have to use `sed`?

Comment: Thanks for your response! No there is no such requirement to use SED but I was wondering in order to use any parsing tools, do I need to install something in UNIX? If not, then it's totally fine.

Comment: What operating system are you using? If UNIX, which one? And are you really using Unix or did you mean Linux?

Comment: I am really sorry. this is Linux. Linux vlheemsdv03 4.12.14-122.12-default #1 SMP Thu Dec 19 12:19:34 UTC 2019 (6c5578e) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Is it SUSE Linux Enterprise Server?

Comment: Obligatory Zalgo reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18356

Answer (score 7):

Using `xmlstarlet`:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -u '//Table/@version[ ../@tableName = "Data" and contains(.,"6.02") ]' -v '6.02' file.xml
```

This finds all `version` attributes of every `Table` node.  It selects the ones belonging the `Table` nodes that also has a `tableName` attribute with the value `Data` *and* that contains the substring `6.02`. These are updated be only the string `6.02`.

The result is written to standard output where you may redirect it into a new file, or you may use `xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u ...` to edit the document in-place (use with care).

Comment: I ma getting error: -ksh: xmlstarlet: not found [No such file or directory]. Also, is it not possible to search the version field only for table Data as 6.02 version can exist for other tables well including "Data". Hence those versions will get updated as well.

Comment: @DebajitDutta You will need to install `xmlstarlet` if it's not already installed. Use your package manager. I will update the answer to also check the `tableName` attribute ASAP.

Comment: What could be the other option if I don't want to install xmlstarlet as I can't really install anything in Production servers?

Comment: @DebajitDutta Then go through whatever protocol you need to go through to introduce `xmlstarlet` on your production servers. I would recommend installing it on the production server over adding broken home-grown XML parsing code that may potentially compromise your production system.

Comment: @DebajitDutta I can't underline that enough: Doing XML parsing using a line-oriented tool like `sed` (or `awk`, by default) is brittle and difficult to get right, but easy to do quick-n-dirty hacky edits with. Using a dedicated XML parser is safer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am already in a process of installing xmlstarlet in Production. Mena while if you could provide the command to also check the tableName attribute what would be a great help.

Comment: @DebajitDutta I'm already checking the `tableName` attribute :-)

Comment: as this is third party package, I would need to go through a lot of approval and there is a chance that they can reject it. Can we have something else like "sed" command. I understand that this is not advisable but still would like to give it a try

Comment: @DebajitDutta You will unfortunately not get a `sed` command that does XML parsing from me.

Comment: There is almost certainly some other language with a proper XML parsing library (e.g. Python) that is installed and/or approved that you can use.

Comment: @chepner Yes, quite likely. I don't do Python really well though, and this is not really that sort of programming site (generic programming questions are better suited for StackOverflow).

Comment: @DebajitDutta `xmlstarlet` is no more a third party program than `sed`, `python`, or even `bash`. It's just not necessarily installed by default. But then on many of my systems not even `ssh` is installed by default; I chose to install only what's necessary. You will find it in your package management system (don't spend effort building it from source).

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: *Never automatically change XML files with* `sed` *unless you are really sure what you are doing. It's usually easy to invent examples where the script will fail. In this case,* `oldversion="..."` *would match, for example.*

```
sed 's/version="\([^",]*,\)*6.02\(,[^",]*\)*"/version="6.02"/g'
```

You don't want the replacement if the is a version number `16.02` or `6.021`, which makes it a little bit ugly to create a pattern. `[^",]*,` matches any string without comma or double quote, followed by a comma, so `\([^",]*,\)*` matches zero or many of those fields. This way we make sure there is no digit or something else before the `6.02`. Same thing for the fields following the version number.

Comment: ok so are you saying this command i can use?

Comment: @DebajitDutta They're saying that it will do what you say you want to do given the exact data in the question (which, may I remind you, isn't even a well-formed XML fragment). Whether or not it will actually work in a production environment, under all circumstances, forever, is up to you to consider.

Comment: Yes, as @Kusalananda wrote, you can use it at your own risk. While the `awk` answer below will easily fail and damage your files, this one will almost certainly do the job. But still XML has some degrees of freedom to make the command fail, if the tool that creates the file uses this freedom. If you really don't have any other option, try it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Will `awk` work?

```bsh
awk '$2~/tableName="Data"/ && $5 ~ /[*",.^]6.02[$.,"*]/ { $5 = "version=\"6.02\">" }1'
```

- **Input**

```
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=1234" DBaction="A" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.02,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=4284" DBaction="B" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.05,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=8827" DBaction="C" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.02,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=1234" DBaction="D" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.06,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=4284" DBaction="E" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.05,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=8827" DBaction="F" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.09,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=1234" DBaction="G" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.02,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=4284" DBaction="H" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.05,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=8827" DBaction="I" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.04,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=1234" DBaction="J" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.02,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=4284" DBaction="K" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.05,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=8827" DBaction="L" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.02,6.03,6.04">
```

- **Output**

```bsh
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=1234" DBaction="A" version="6.02">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=4284" DBaction="B" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.05,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=8827" DBaction="C" version="6.02">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=1234" DBaction="D" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.06,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=4284" DBaction="E" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.05,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=8827" DBaction="F" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.09,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=1234" DBaction="G" version="6.02">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=4284" DBaction="H" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.05,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=8827" DBaction="I" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.04,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=1234" DBaction="J" version="6.02">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=4284" DBaction="K" version="14.1,20.4,4.30,4.40,5.00,5.30,5.40,5.41,6.00,6.01,6.05,6.03,6.04">
<Table tableName="Data" primaryKey="PGPU_ID=8827" DBaction="L" version="6.02">
```

Comment: This requires that the attributes are ordered in a particular way, with no newlines between them. It also assumes that the string `,6.02,` does not occur in the fifth on any other line than in the lines that we'd like to change. This will break if the `Table` node has any data after it, on the same line, that needs to be retained (or updated, if there are more `Table` nodes on the same line).

Comment: I updated it to include the original data that would not be altered if 6.02 does not appear in the version list.

Comment: What about if `6.02` is the first or the last version number in the list?